# How to use multiple schema registry url in prepare_producer() , pyhton

Tags: python, apache-kafka, confluent-schema-registry

I try to push my message to the Kafka topic using multiple schema registry URLs but the prepare_producer() method allows only on the registry URL, is there any way to give multiple schema registry URLs?

```
from kafka_schema_registry import prepare_producer

SAMPLE_SCHEMA = {
    "type": "record",
    "name": "TestType",
    "fields" : [
        {"name": "age", "type": "int"},
        {"name": "name", "type": ["null", "string"]}
    ]
}


producer = prepare_producer(
        ['localhost:9092'],
        f'http://schemaregistry',
        topic_name,
        1,
        1,
        value_schema=SAMPLE_SCHEMA,
)

producer.send(topic_name, {'age': 34})
```

I want to replace the URL "http://schemaregistry" with another multiple schema registry URL.

Answer (score 0):

The `confluent_kafka_python` Schema Registry address accepts a CSV list.

Or, you can setup a reverse proxy, single address, for your Registry cluster.

Both options will load balance into "one" Registry (since there's one master server).

You'll need to use a plain loop to register to distinct Registries, however, it's not good practice to have more than one for one Kafka cluster.